# Why is returning a reference to const pointer allowed in constexpr function, but not returning a copy?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have the following 3 C++ files (the problem does not occur if all are in 1 file):

clazz.hpp:

```
class Clazz {
    public:
        static const char* const NAME;
};
```

clazz.cpp:

```
#include "clazz.hpp"
const char* const Clazz::NAME = "Clazz";
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clazz.hpp"

constexpr const char* const& get_clazz_name_ref() {
    return Clazz::NAME;
}

constexpr const char* get_clazz_name() {
    return Clazz::NAME; // this does not work
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << get_clazz_name_ref() << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_clazz_name() << std::endl;
}
```

When compiling this files in Visual Studio 2015, I get an error message for the `get_clazz_name` function:

```
error C3256: 'NAME': variable use does not produce a constant expression
```

Funnily enough, the function `get_clazz_name_ref` is compiled OK. Why is that so?

---

In response to Alan Stokes https://stackoverflow.com/a/36112146/59557 : why is this working?

clazz.hpp:

```
#include <array>
class Clazz {
    public:
        static const char* const NAME;
        static const size_t N = 3;
        static const std::array<const char*, N> NAMES;
};
```

clazz.cpp:

```
#include "clazz.hpp"
const char* const Clazz::NAME = "Clazz";

const std::array<const char*, Clazz::N> Clazz::NAMES = {
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clazz.hpp"

constexpr const char* const& get_clazz_name_ref() {
    return Clazz::NAME;
}

constexpr const char* get_name(size_t i) {
    return Clazz::NAMES[i];
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << get_clazz_name_ref() << std::endl;
    std::cout << get_name(0) << std::endl;
}
```

I could change `clazz.cpp` and rebuild, too.

Comment: Your code does not compile if I put everything in the same file.

Comment: Hmm, I thought it did compile for me. Maybe I missed an error message.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Maybe you could post the full code that compiles?

Comment: This compiles for me in Visual Studio 2015:
`#include <iostream>

class Clazz {
public:
 static const char* const NAME;
};

const char* const Clazz::NAME = "Clazz";


constexpr const char* const& get_clazz_name_ref() {
 return Clazz::NAME;
}

constexpr const char* get_clazz_name() {
 return Clazz::NAME;
}

int main(void) {
 std::cout << get_clazz_name_ref() << std::endl;
 std::cout << get_clazz_name() << std::endl;
}`

Comment: `g++` (TDM) rejects  this code with the following error: `the value of 'Clazz::NAME' is not usable in a constant expression [...] note: 'Clazz::NAME' was not declared 'constexpr'`.

Comment: Looks like a discrepancy between VS and g++. Which one is correct?

Comment: I don't know, this may be another question for SO ;)

Comment: For your specific example, they're both correct. `get_clazz_name()` can never be a core constant expression, but compilers are not *required* to diagnose that unless you actually try to use it as such. You need to create a context that requires a constant expression; for example, `constexpr auto a = get_clazz_name();`, and similar for your other example. That said, MSVC will still accept this in your one-file example, which is incorrect - `Clazz::NAME` should be declared `constexpr`; `const` is enough only in some very specific cases (integers or `enum`s initialized with constants). cc @Holt

Comment: So, if you change your one-file example as described above, you will actually encounter a bug in MSVC. If you want to report the issue on MS Connect, please go ahead, otherwise, I can do it (it may have already been reported, I haven't checked).

Comment: It interesting that Intellisense is reporting the error as you say it should, but compiler accepts the code. I will submit a bug report, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The address of `NAME` is known to the compiler when compiling `main.cpp` but its value isn't. So the value can't be a compile-time constant.

(You could change `clazz.cpp` only and rebuild, to give it a different value; so it can't be constant.)

That doesn't apply when they're in one file because then the initialiser is visible and the value is known.

Comment: I get your explanation, but then how come extracting `const char*` values from a `std::array` member of `Clazz`, defined in `clazz.cpp`, can be made `constexpr` (see updated question).